# Arrange tiles in Windows 8 by Most Recently Used

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 8, is there a way to have tiles automatically arranged by most recently used application (ala Windows 7 start menu)? Maybe with a few pinned in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar option is available in Windows 8.1, which will be available as a free update later this year. Windows 8.1 allows you to see the "most used apps" first.

[image]